# Is there a way to define configuration structure for intellisense with "config" npm package?

Tags: javascript, typescript, config, node-config

I am using `config` module from npm with JS or TS.
let's imagine I have the following `default.json`:

```json
{
  "database": {
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
 }
}
```

then somewhere in my code I write

```js
import config from "config";
// ...
config.get('database.username') //
```

**Thing I would like to have is some kind of hint during coding of what I can get from `config`.**
I can think of usage of constants like

```js
const CONFIG = {
  DATABASE: {
    USERNAME: "database.username",
    PASSWORD: "database.password"
  }
}
// and then
const { DATABASE } = CONFIG;
config.get(DATABASE.USERNAME)
```

but maybe there is some other way, more automatic than manual as we already have this information in configuration files.

**Is there a way to achieve this?**

Comment: You can use a [schema](https://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step.html). Many IDEs support it.

Comment: @jabaa but how does this apply in my case? to get value from `config` I need to get it's string name with dot accessors. How schema will improve intellisence ?

Comment: Usually a config file has a static, documented structure. This structure is described in the schema and your IDE will read this schema.